# How i can by pass Cloud Flare in Jmeter load test to access on my server for real hits?

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, stress-testing

I have applied load on my website for particular listeners but all my hits went to Cloud Flare & doesn't hit my server to Real check the load on my website.
I have verified it through assertion on JMeter that it only hits to cloud flare.

Any one can tell me how to by pass cloud flare to load the real test of website.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b48Jf.jpg)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite hard to come up with a comprehensive answer without knowing the cloudflare and your website configuration, if this is the case that cloudflare checks for the source [IP address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address) you can try going for [IP Spoofing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-ip-spoofing-simulate-requests-different-ip-addresses-jmeter/)

You can also try adding the [DNS Cache Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#DNS_Cache_Manager) to your test plan so each JMeter thread would resolve the IP address beyond the hostname of your website individually and not relying on the JVM and/or OS DNS caching mechanisms.